# (Java) Trying to figure out how to read from a .txt file

Tags: java

I'm quite new to Java and I have a project, I'm trying to create my own text file and then print numbers from my program to the textfile.

Then I want the software to read the numbers afterwards again and show what of the numbers that is the biggest one.

So far this is what I've done:

```
    String fil = "C:\\Java\\Test.txt";
    BufferedWriter fout = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(fil, true));
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Skriv in tre tal: ");
    int x = in.nextInt();
    int y = in.nextInt();
    int z = in.nextInt();
    fout.write(x + " " + y + " " + z);
    fout.newLine();
    fout.flush();

    BufferedReader fin = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fil));
    String s = fin.readLine();
    System.out.println(s);
```

I just don't know how to make my software find the biggest number in the code and then print it out.

Thanks in advance
/Fsociety1337

Comment: Some information would be great. What happens? Any errors/exceptions?

Comment: Essentially, it works until the end. It prints out whatever I write to the file, but I don't know how to or what to use to read the numbers again and show what number is the biggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A complete solution would be:

```
public class LargestNumberFinder {

  public static final String FILENAME = "C:\\Java\\Test.txt";

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
      BufferedWriter fout = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(FILENAME, true));
      Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.print("Skriv in tre tal: ");
      int x = in.nextInt();
      int y = in.nextInt();
      int z = in.nextInt();
      fout.write(x + " " + y + " " + z);
      fout.newLine();
      fout.flush();

      BufferedReader fin = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(FILENAME));
      String s = fin.readLine();
      System.out.println(s);

      int largest = getLargestNumberFromFile(FILENAME);
      System.out.println("The largest number is: " + largest);
  }

  private static int getLargestNumberFromFile(String filename) throws FileNotFoundException {
      int largest = -1;
      Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File(filename));
      scanner.useDelimiter(" |[\\r\\n]+");
      while(scanner.hasNext()) {
          int currentNumber = scanner.nextInt();
          if (currentNumber > largest) {
              largest = currentNumber;
          }
      }
      scanner.close();

      return largest;
  }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Split the reponded String into 3 Integer variables and just compare them.

Comment: Ah that sounds nice! Do you know how to split a string into 3 ints?

Comment: You could add commas as split-points and Simply use String[] parts = string.split(", ");    to split the String.    You can access the result by creating new Strings:  String part1 = parts[0];       and the these you can case to Integer by using part1.parseInt(); i think.

Comment: *you can cast to Integer...   Not case, sorry.